# Silverlight: Copy/Paste Context Menu with TextBox (Text Highlighting Issue)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have created a `TextBox` control:

```
public class MyTextbox : TextBox
```

which is a just a normal `TextBox`, to which I have added a behavior that I have written:

```
    public class TextBoxCutCopyPasteBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
```

Everything works fine and dandy: right-clicking will display a `ContextMenu` with Cut, Copy, Paste options.  **However**, the `TextBox` text ceases to be highlighted at that point, since the `TextBox` has lost focus.

*What would the best way be to make the selected text remain highlighted, even after the `ContextMenu` appears and the `TextBox` loses focus?*

Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to access the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the TextBox

```
private void CopyMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string textToCopy = MyTextBox.SelectedText;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn -- that is not the issue, perhaps I should have been clearer.  I just want the text to remain highlighted, so that the users get a consistent experience...  It is confusing when it unhighlights, then rehighlights when you click back in the box.